# Cómo puedo poner la cantidad de productos que hay en el carrito en mi navbar Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un carrito de compras que funciona con la sesión del navegador. El carrito funciona bien.. pero me gustaría poner un contador que tenga la cantidad de productos que hay en el carrito

Mi controlador

```
use Tienda\Producto;
class CarritoController extends Controller
{
    //constructor para crear el carrito
    public function __construct(){
        // Si no existe la variable de sesion cart, entonces lo crea en un array
        if(!\Session::has('cart')) \Session::put('cart', array());

    }
    //mostrar carrito
    public function show(){
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');//obtener la variable de sesion
        $total = $this->total();//precio total
        $delivery = 0.10;
        return view('user.producto.cart', compact('cart', 'total'));
    }

    //agregar productos al carrito
    public function add(Producto $product){
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');//recibe la variable de sesion y lo guarda en una variable local
        $product->quantity = 1; //la cantidad del producto es 1 por default
        $cart[$product->pro_id] = $product;//obtenemos guardamos nuestros productos atraves del slug en el array $cart-show
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);//actualiza la variable de sesion
        return redirect()->route('cart-show');//retorna a la vista del carrito

    }
    //metodo para actualizar cantidad en el carrito
    public function update(Producto $product, $quantity){
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $cart[$product->pro_id]->quantity = $quantity;//obtengo la cantidad que selecciono el usuario y lo guardo
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }
    //metodo para eliminar productos del carrito
    public function delete(Producto $product){
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        unset($cart[$product->pro_id]);//borra elementos del carrito
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('cart-show');        

    }

    //metodo para vaciar el carrito
    public function trash(){
        \Session::forget('cart'); //vacia el carrito con forget()
        return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }


    private function total(){//funcion privada por que solo se va a utilizar aca
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $total = 0;
        foreach($cart as $item){
            $total += $item->price * $item->quantity;
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function orderDetail(){
        if(count(\Session::get('cart')) <= 0) return redirect()->url('/');//si no hay productos en el carrito
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $total = $this->total();
        return view('user.producto.order-detail', compact('cart', 'total'));
    }
}
```

mi vista del carrito

```
@extends('layouts.user')
@section('principal')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('frontend/plugins/flexslider/flexslider.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('frontend/styles/product_responsive.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('frontend/styles/cart.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('frontend/styles/cart_responsive.css')}}">

    <div class="super_container"><br><br><br><br><br>

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="super_container_inner">
            <div class="super_overlay"></div>


            <div class="cart_section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="cart_container">

                                <!-- Cart Bar -->
                                <div class="cart_bar">
                                    <ul class="cart_bar_list item_list d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-end">
                                        <li class="mr-auto">Producto</li>
                                        <li>Color</li>
                                        <li>Tamaño</li>
                                        <li>Precio</li>
                                        <li>Cantidad</li>
                                        <li>Sub_Total</li>
                                        <li>Quitar</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Cart Items -->
                                <div class="cart_items">
                                    <ul class="cart_items_list">
                                        <!-- Cart Item -->
                                        @foreach($cart as $item)
                                            <li class="cart_item item_list d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-lg-end justify-content-start">
                                                <div class="product d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start mr-auto">

                                                    <div><div class="product_image"><img src="{{asset('imagenes/productos/'.$item->pro_foto)}}" alt=""></div></div>
                                                    <div class="product_name_container">
                                                        <div class="product_name"><a href="#">{{$item->pro_nom}}</a></div>
                                                        <div class="product_text">{{$item->pro_info}}</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_color product_text"><span>Color: </span>beige</div>
                                                <div class="product_size product_text"><span>Tamaño: </span>L</div>
                                                <div class="product_price product_text"><span>Precio: </span>{{$item->pro_precio}}</div>
                                                <div class="product_quantity_container">
                                                    <div class="product_quantity ml-lg-auto mr-lg-auto text-center">
                                                        <span class="product_text product_num">1</span>
                                                        <div class="qty_sub qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>-</span></div>
                                                        <div class="qty_add qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>+</span></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product_total product_text"><span>Total: </span>$3.99</div>
                                                <div class="product_total product_text">
                                                    <a href="{{ route('cart-delete', $item->pro_id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Cart Buttons -->
                                <div class="cart_buttons d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
                                    <div class="cart_buttons_inner ml-sm-auto d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start flex-wrap">
                                        <div class="button button_clear trans_200"><a href="{{url('vaciar')}}">vaciar carrito</a></div>
                                        <div class="button button_continue trans_200"><a href="{{url('/user/producto/index')}}">cotinuar comprando</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cart_extra_row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="cart_extra cart_extra_1">
                                <div class="cart_extra_content cart_extra_coupon">
                                    <div class="cart_extra_title">Coupon code</div>
                                    <div class="coupon_form_container">
                                        <form action="#" id="coupon_form" class="coupon_form">
                                            <input type="text" class="coupon_input" required="required">
                                            <button class="coupon_button">apply</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="coupon_text">Phasellus sit amet nunc eros. Sed nec congue tellus. Aenean nulla nisl, volutpat blandit lorem ut.</div>
                                    <div class="shipping">
                                        <div class="cart_extra_title">Shipping Method</div>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="shipping_option d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                                <label class="radio_container">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="shipping_radio" class="shipping_radio">
                                                    <span class="radio_mark"></span>
                                                    <span class="radio_text">Next day delivery</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="shipping_price ml-auto">$4.99</div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="shipping_option d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                                <label class="radio_container">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="shipping_radio" class="shipping_radio">
                                                    <span class="radio_mark"></span>
                                                    <span class="radio_text">Standard delivery</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="shipping_price ml-auto">$1.99</div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="shipping_option d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                                <label class="radio_container">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="radio_3" name="shipping_radio" class="shipping_radio" checked>
                                                    <span class="radio_mark"></span>
                                                    <span class="radio_text">Personal Pickup</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="shipping_price ml-auto">Free</div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 cart_extra_col">
                            <div class="cart_extra cart_extra_2">
                                <div class="cart_extra_content cart_extra_total">
                                    <div class="cart_extra_title">Cart Total</div>
                                    <ul class="cart_extra_total_list">
                                        <li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_title">Subtotal</div>
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_value ml-auto">$29.90</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_title">Shipping</div>
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_value ml-auto">Free</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_title">Total</div>
                                            <div class="cart_extra_total_value ml-auto">$29.90</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="checkout_button trans_200"><a href="checkout.html">proceed to checkout</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
        </div>
            <script src="{{ asset('frontend/js/cart.js') }}"></script>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

y mi navbar

```
<div class="header_right d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start ml-auto">
                <!-- Cart -->
                <div class="user"><a href="#"><div><img src="{{asset('frontend/images/cart.svg')}}" alt="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik"><div>1 (debe aumentar solo)</div></div></a></div>
                <!-- Phone -->
                <div class="header_phone d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                    <div><div><img src="{{asset('frontend/images/phone.svg')}}" alt="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik"></div></div>
                    <div>+595992244017</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

en donde dice debe aumentar solo es donde debería ir el contador...

Como este carrito funciona con variables de sesión. mi pregunta es. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para contar los productos que hay en el carrito y que se muestre en todas las paginas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si está en la session, puede utilizar la función [count()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) para obtener la cantidad de elementos en el Array.

```
{{ count( \Session::get('cart') }}
```

Tener en cuenta que puede utilizar directamente el [helper session()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-session)

```
{{ count(session('cart')) }}
```

Comment: pero como hago para poner eso en mi plantilla master? ya que se debe ver en todas las vistas... y no puedo ponerlo en un controlador y asignarle una ruta no?

Comment: @HernanChaparro añada directamente en la plantilla master el código de mi respuesta, las variables de sesión están disponibles para todas sus plantillas.